# How to maintain established connections android when changing wireless network

Tags: applications, wi-fi, networking

I need to resolve the following problem. I runs my application android conected with my server on cloud, but my established connections disappears when I switch the (Wi-Fi) wireless network.

Why this problem? In notebooks and tablets does not happen.

Comment: Your notebook/tablet might be able to recover a connection (ie. continue by updating connection details) but your phone might take too long or even close all connections when switching networks.

Comment: OK, thanks. But there is a solution to maintain the connection?